# MFC Custom HtmlHelp

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2008, mfc, html-help

I'm doing maintenance on a legacy MFC application. When the user selects Help → Help from the main menu along the top of the app, I need my custom `OnHelp()` to be called. From my research, I've learned that MFC normally intercepts this command automatically and brings up your help file itself. But you can override this command and intercept this message yourself. I have this in my message map:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyApp, MyBaseApp)
   //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(MyApp)
   ON_COMMAND(ID_APP_ABOUT, OnAppAbout)
   ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, OnHelp)
   //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
   // Standard file based document commands
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The "About" `OnAppAbout()` gets called, but not my `OnHelp()` (MFC still intercepts it and brings up the help by itself). My implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
void MyApp::OnHelp()
{
    // This never gets called
   MessageBox( NULL, "HtmlHelp: MyApp", "Hey", MB_OK );

   CString csHelpFile;
   csHelpFile.Format( "%s/MyHelp.chm", MyDoc::GetHelpPath() );
   ::HtmlHelp(
       NULL,
       csHelpFile,
       HELP_WM_HELP,
       NULL );
}
```

I know it's not getting called because my MessageBox never appears (I can't use Visual Studio to debug this; message boxes only). I also tried to wedge it into the `CMDIFrameWnd`, with the message map and similar implementation, with no success either (a different item from the Help menu item is implemented here and works fine). Any idea what I need to do to hook into my own custom help function?

Comment: Are you sure ID_HELP is not handled elsewhere? your app is usually be the last one to get a command message. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shfzay75(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Add another menu item, e.g. ID_HELP2, and try and trap that. If that works then something else is intercepting ID_HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ON_WM_HELPINFO()` into your CMainFrame's message map. Define `afx_msg BOOL OnHelpInfo(HELPINFO* pHelpInfo);` in your header file for the Main Frame, and implement it in the cpp file:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnHelpInfo(HELPINFO* pHelpInfo)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
  MessageBox( NULL, "HtmlHelp: MyApp", "Hey", MB_OK );
#endif

  CString csHelpFile;
  csHelpFile.Format( "%s/MyHelp.chm", MyDoc::GetHelpPath() );
  ::HtmlHelp(
   NULL,
   csHelpFile,
   HELP_WM_HELP,
   NULL );
  return CFrameWnd::OnHelpInfo(pHelpInfo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked PERFECT for F1. Unfortunately, selecting Help | Help still gets handled by MFC. Still have to find out how to circumvent that...